# In the Ubiquity RPG system, what is the advantage of using continuous combat?

Tags: combat, initiative, ubiquity

In the Ubiquity RPG system (as used in Hollow Earth Expedition or Space 1889), an alternative initiative system ("continuous combat", where actions take place continuously, without use of combat turns) is proposed in addition to the default system (a turn based system relatively similar to Dungeons and Dragons).   Continuous combat is left a bit vague in the core rulebook, but elaborated on in the addendum to the Hollow Earth Expedition GM screen.

What are the advantages (as a GM) of using continuous combat?
Is it very complicated to use?
When would it shine compared to the standard initiative system?
When is it worse?

Comment: You're right, I've totally messed this up. Continuous combat is *more* complex than normal round-robin combat, not vice versa. Do you have access to Hollow Earth Expedition GM Screen? It has some more information on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

The advantages are that combat is more granular and step-by-step.
Combat is broken into phases, with ten phases equaling one combat turn.

Page 117 says:

> Using the continuous combat  option  makes  using  weaker,  faster  weapons more attractive because a character with a high initiative and a fast weapon may get to strike more frequently than an opponent using something slower. Effects which take one combat turn (such as suffering from continuous poison damage or needing to roll to  stabilize  while  dying)  occur  every  ten  phases.  For example, a character that was stunned on phase 56 will get to attack again on phase 66.

It would shine if you wanted a more deadly but nuanced combat, and it would be worse if you want to keep things simple and fast. It's complicated to use, you're getting more detail by breaking down the turn into more parts.